# equals of case class with non-primitives is not working correctly for two logically equal instances

Tags: scala, equals, case-class

Equals is not working correctly for two logically equals instance of case class.
Please find below simplified case classes :-

```
case class Item(name : String)
case class Basket(items : Array[Item], bills : Map[Int, Int])

def createBasketInstance() : Basket = {
  val maggi = Item("milk")
  val coffee = Item("coffee")

  val bills1 = Map(1 -> 20, 2 -> 75)
  Basket( Array(maggi, coffee), bills1 )
}

val basket1 = createBasketInstance()
val basket2 = createBasketInstance()
```

Expected Result for **basket1.equals(basket2)** is true, but it actually prints false.

scalafiddle link : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/iJRKnMk/0

Please find attached screenshot also to confirm equals comparison using scalatest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the default `equals` of the `case classes` but that of the `Arrays`  (this is one of the millions reasons you should use `Lists` over `Arrays` btw)

In Scala Arrays are just plain Java arrays and arrays in Java are treated specially (because JVM)

Even a simple

```
Array(1, 2, 3) == Array(1, 2, 3)
```

will return false.

Why? Because `Object.equals` which the Arrays inherit the `equals` method from only compared the **array references** and NOT their content.

I know this doesn't sound as bad as it is, but believe it gets worse.

You might think simply assigning your array to a value would fix it right? Well it doesn't. The following will fail as well...

```
def createBasketInstance() : Basket = {
  val maggi = Item("milk")
  val coffee = Item("coffee")
  val arr =  Array(maggi, coffee)
  val bills1 = Map(1 -> 20, 2 -> 75)
  Basket( arr, bills1 )
}
```

Because the call stacks of the different invocation of this function is not able to share references and thus each function call fill create a new reference even though the underlying content is the same.

How do you solve this?

1. There is a method in `java.utils.Arrays` called `Arrays.equals` that will do a deep comparison. You can `override` it and construct it such that the comparison uses `Arrays.equals`. You might also need to override `hashCode`
2. Write an implicit conversion from `Array` to literally any other collection
3. Don't use Arrays in the first place.

I would say #3 is the way to go about this